# ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - existing app that use UIWebView are no longer accepted

Tags: ios, uiwebview, app-store, app-store-connect, wkwebview

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will no longer accept submissions of new apps that use UIWebView as of April 30, 2020 and app updates that use UIWebView as of December 2020. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability.

I am trying to update an existing app, not a new app. Still I am not able to upload the app. I got this error via email:

---

```
We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "App Name" 20202.421.1 (6). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).
```

---

Did Apple change its policy or something? Or do I need to change `UIWebView`?

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler No. It seems but its not...please read it first...I am aware of the fact that UIWebView is getting depricated but for new app. for old apps they mentioned dec 2020 deadline.

and still I am not abel to update my existing app

Comment: Have you ever released a build of this app with this bundle id to the App Store?

Comment: Yes..i did...I have my app live on app store at this time...and I want to update it

Comment: I had the same problem for my existing app (2+ years on App Store). I did have one component that was still using UIWebView and had to migrate that to WKWebView. Strange since existing apps should still not be rejected until Dec 2020. I also just started happening randomly in the beginning of May. Did work for a couple of days in May so it's trange that the April 30 deadline didn't cause this issue.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, Apple did change the policies
Are you using ionic? if so, install these:

1. `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@latest`
2. `npm install @ionic-native/ionic-webview`

Then add this to your **config.xml** under ios platform:

```
<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">`
<param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

Finally run `ionic cordova prepare ios` to reflect the changes
then run `ionic cordova build ios --prod`

PS: Make sure you have only one webview plugin installed.. either this or the 'cordova-webviewengine'. But the above method worked for me and my app is in app store now

Comment: Verified on Ionic v5. Thanks @Sireesha!

Comment: I don't know if you'll be able to help with this but after doing this, i'm getting some new errors. Before, it launched my app and I was able to login but now, it still launches it but I am getting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin cannot contain more than one origin.` and `XMLHttpRequest cannot load due to access control checks`. The only thing that's changed are the changes made on your post.

Comment: @J.Do, looks like the issus is with the API you are calling.. Have you tried to see if all you requests are being handled correctly?

Answer (score 32):

In Terminal, run this command in your iOS project folder:

```
grep -r "UIWebView" .
```

It will show all the files that uses UIWebview. Update whatever files to use WKWebView. If your pod libraries are showing that it has UIWebView. Update the pods files as well.

FYI it took me 6 hours to fix my project to use WKWebView since I had to update the pods files and had to fix a lot of code.

Comment: Don't forget the . (point) at end of [grep -r "UIWebView" .] like I did...

Comment: Great solution. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @user1733372, can you tell how to update pods? I don't know anything about pods.

Comment: Used your solution and as it turns out the UIWebView was being used in one of the dependencies. So, I updated that library to the latest version and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 11):

i faced the same issue few days earlier for my IONIC 4 Project.
when i uploaded my IPA, i got this warnings from App Store Connect.

[image]

I fixed the "UIWebView" issue, by the following steps. hope it will also work for you.

Follow this steps :

1. Run the following command to Remove the existing platform.

   `ionic cordova platform rm ios`
2. remove the existing web view plugin and install the latest one.

   `ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview`

   `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@latest`
3. Install this also.

   `npm install @ionic-native/ionic-webview@latest`
4. Add this to your config.xml file under the ios part.

   `<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" /> <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine"> <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" /> </feature> <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />`
5. check your `"cordova-ios": "^5.1.1"` version. it should be `5.1.x` or greater.
6. then run this commands to build again.

   `ionic cordova platform add ios`

   `ionic cordova prepare ios`

   `ionic cordova build ios`

that's all. it worked for me.

---

My Package.json file :

[image]

[image]

Sharing my config.xml also :

[image]

Follow this link for more info :

https://ionicframework.com/blog/understanding-itms-90809-uiwebview-api-deprecation/

Thanks.

Comment: Hi I after updating config.xml I am facing "Received memory pressure event 2 vm pressure 0" My app will reload again. What is wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

facebook4, googleplus, fcm older version of these cordova plugins also using UIWebView. need to use latest versions

Answer (score 2):

For Xamarin Form projects, here is the fix:

Go to your iOS project, open the project properties and add this flag in the additional mtouch arguments field: `--optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type` this flag works together with the Linker Behavior set to SDK Only or All.

Read more from Microsoft: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 2):

In my case, There was no `UIWebView` in my project but still apple shows the above error. Then I find out the files which contain UIWebView using the following steps.

Step 1.Open terminal
Step 2. cd  then hit enter.
Step 3. paste this command
`grep -r "UIWebView" .`
Then you will find the file list.

In my case. I remove GoogleAdMobSDK from project and install it again using pod.
https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start

If you never used pod then learn "How to use pod" on youtube.

After installing pod. Apple accepted my project.

Huh. Finally solved.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and fixed through these steps:

1. Update webview plugin

```sh
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@latest
npm install @ionic-native/ionic-webview
```

2. Add some configuration to `config.xml` file

```xml
<allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*" />
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
<platform name="ios">
    <resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
    <preference name="InAppBrowserStatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

3. Remove or update social sharing plugin (if you use it)

```sh
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing@latest --save 
npm install @ionic-native/social-sharing@latest --save
```

4. Remove and add iOS platform again

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same problem in **Ionic 4**.

List of steps followed to fix the problem

please update your IOS platform. and App browser .

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

run cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

detele node_modules , then reinstall by run yarn or npm install

run ionic cordova platform rm ios

run ionic cordova platform add ios@5.1.1

npm i cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@3.2.0

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@3.2.0

ionic cordova prepare ios.

ionic cordova build ios
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer [here](https://ionicframework.com/blog/understanding-itms-90809-uiwebview-api-deprecation/#comment-4898560621) solved my problem

```
cordova prepare ios
npm install -g cordova-check-plugins
npm install -g npm
cordova-check-plugins --update=auto
npm update -g cordova
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform rm ios
npm i -g @ionic/cli
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@3.2.0
ionic cordova platform remove ios && ionic cordova platform add ios@latest && ionic cordova build ios
```

Answer (score 0):

### I get rid out from this by following below steps (in react-native project)-

Step 1:

> Search “UIWebView” in xcode project directory

Step 2:

> Right click (on RCTWebView.m) and select “Reveal In Project Navigator”

Step 3:

> Scroll down and delete the following four files only:

```
 1. RCTWebView.h
 2. RCTWebView.m
 3. RCTWebViewManager.h
 4. RCTWebViewManager.m
```

Then clean the project & archive.

N.B: If you use *'react-native-community/react-native-webview'* library then update with latest version otherwise it's done.

Answer (score 0):

update your package (like for example react-native-device-info).

**Its working**

```
 in package.json update device-info to latest
"react-native-device-info": "^8.0.8",

run this command in terminal

grep -r UIWebView node_modules/*



ignored for contexts returned by UIWebView. */
node_modules/react-addons-shallow-compare/node_modules/fbjs/lib/UserAgent.js.flow:   * - UIWebView
node_modules/react-addons-shallow-compare/node_modules/fbjs/lib/UserAgent.js:   * - UIWebView
node_modules/recyclerlistview/node_modules/fbjs/lib/UserAgent.js.flow:   * - UIWebView
node_modules/recyclerlistview/node_modules/fbjs/lib/UserAgent.js:   * - UIWebView
node_modules/ua-parser-js/test/browser-test.json:        "ua"      : "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14A456 QQ/6.5.3.410 V1_IPH_SQ_6.5.3_1_APP_A Pixel/1080 Core/UIWebView NetType/WIFI Mem/26",
DT-67iMac-2:IGPSYARD stigasoft$ 


yarn upgrade react-addons-shallow-compare recyclerlistview ua-parser-jss

cd ios

  rm -rf Pods # probably not needed.  (delete pods and podfile.lock file and again pod install)

pod install
```

[more details](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26255)

Built my project, tested everything was still working and submitted to Apple.
This time there was no message about using a depreciated API.