# How to upload Old Cordova iOS App to the App Store with WKWebView

Tags: ios, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, cordova-ios

Cordova iOS is giving me a very hard time. I have a Cordova iOS app written in 2016 and I am handling it now.

I believe you are familiar with the following app store issues regarding UIWebView:

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted.
>
> Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

Now my application is quite huge; it has Apple Pay feature, biometrics, lots of bridge calls between website and iOS app.

I tried to update Cordova in my app and then uploaded it, but it never worked. So I find out that first the physical structure of my app was wrong, all I had in my source tree is 'src' folder which had everything. So I created "hello world" Cordova iOS project from terminal (command line) and then noticed the difference of folders and files like config.xml hooks, nodeModules etc ..

Now my solution was to create a sample helloworld app and then copy my code into ios folder (platform->iOS-> My 100 files). But it did work. I followed this link: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

And i thought if i follow following lines of code in terminal :

```
cordova create wkwvtest my.project.id wkwvtest
cd wkwvtest
cordova platform add ios@4
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine
```

I will create a Cordova app which will have ios 4 version of Cordova and then WKWebView will be integrated in my app and then i will be able to upload this app on app store.

But even this sample application gives me app store error of deprecated UIWebView. Has anyone found the clear cut solution to this problem?

Q1: Have you ever uploaded a sample test app like hello world to the TestFlight which has Cordova ios 4.1+ or even cordova ios 5.1+ version. Because I am assuming in Cordova wkwebview plugin all things related to uiwebview has already been handled or atleast in the latest version it has been handled and we don't need to do anything else apart from installing latest Cordova ios version.

Question 2: What should I do to upload my app on app store it has cordova-ios 4.1.1 right now. I tried many possible ways. Like for eg a) created a sample cordova-ios app with latest Cordova ios 5.1.1 and copied all my source files (almost 100-500) into ios folder, removed all uiwebview instance in my code (almost 50 places), but when I search for 'uiwebview' cordova library still has almost 120 search results.

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61790543/itms-90809-deprecated-api-usage-existing-app-that-use-uiwebview-are-no-longer

Comment: YES already did , as my applicaiton is big and using cordova ios 4.1.1 and also i feel that it does not have package.json , node modules , hooks , platform folders . my situation is diffrent , some how it is working fine as cordova hybrid app. i added all those folders and files and placed my files inside ios folder . but keeping the latest corodva library and project same . rest of the files i copied into ios folder. am i missing any thing or doing wrong here ?

Comment: Hi Rakesh. Please install an English spell-checker into your browser - doing so is usually one-click these days.

Comment: @halfer please help me point out some of the mis-spelled words . i will correct those. Also if you have a solution, please point out .

Comment: They've been corrected already, [see the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62538448/revisions). It's worth bearing in mind that Stack Overflow is not a chat room or a forum; it's a Q&A site where the questions and answers are kept for years in order to help new readers. For that reason, we want questions to be clear and readable. No everyone is expected to be proficient in English, but a everyone can use a spell-checker.