# ionic v3 build IOS get error “UIWebView” when upload to app store

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

I developed ionic v3 app and i want to upload it to app store when i build the app rejected.

> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app.
> Please correct the following issues, then upload again. the following
> email sent to my by apple.
>
> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no
> longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and
> reliability. Learn more
> (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

but i not using Bluetooth and using one signal.
i using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61790543/itms-90809-deprecated-api-usage-existing-app-that-use-uiwebview-are-no-longer) to remove UIWebView but get me the same error.

my package.json

```
{
  
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts  build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
    "@ionic-native/admob-free": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/deeplinks": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/email-composer": "4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/geofence": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-geocoder": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/paypal": "4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/push": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/spinner-dialog": "4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/stripe": "4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/toast": "4.18.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^0.1.0",
    "cordova-admob-sdk": "^0.24.1",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
    "cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-admob-free": "^0.27.0",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-email-composer": "^0.8.15",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-native-spinner": "^1.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": "^3.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.6.8",
    "cordova-promise-polyfill": "0.0.2",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.3.2",
    "css-animator": "^2.3.1",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-img-viewer": "^2.9.0",
    "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": "^1.0.20",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ng-lazyload-image": "^3.4.2",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.8.3",
    "phonegap-plugin-multidex": "^1.0.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-push": "^2.3.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "woocommerce-api": "^1.5.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.4.1",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.4.1",
    "@ionic/lab": "2.0.10",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-native-spinner": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-email-composer": {},
      "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "To locate you"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": {
        "LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION": "Use geocoder service"
      },
      "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": {
        "URL_SCHEME": "myapp",
        "DEEPLINK_SCHEME": "https",
        "DEEPLINK_HOST": "aromixgroup.com",
        "ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "ANDROID_2_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "ANDROID_3_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "ANDROID_4_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "ANDROID_5_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "DEEPLINK_2_SCHEME": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_2_HOST": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_3_SCHEME": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_3_HOST": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_4_SCHEME": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_4_HOST": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_5_SCHEME": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_5_HOST": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
      
        "FACEBOOK_HYBRID_APP_EVENTS": "false",
        "FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION": "5.0.2"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-admob-free": {
        
      },
      "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-push": {
        
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V13_VERSION": "27.+",
        "FCM_VERSION": "17.0.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_ADD_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app requires photo library access to function properly.",
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app requires photo library access to function properly."
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget  version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
    <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="29" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
        <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
            <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
        </feature>
        <access origin="ionic://localhost" />
        <allow-navigation href="ionic://localhost/*" />
        <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
        <icon height="20" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20.png" width="20" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@2x.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@3x.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="48" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-24@2x.png" width="48" />
        <icon height="55" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-27.5@2x.png" width="55" />
        <icon height="88" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-44@2x.png" width="88" />
        <icon height="172" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-86@2x.png" width="172" />
        <icon height="196" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-98@2x.png" width="196" />
        <icon height="216" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-108@2x.png" width="216" />
        <splash height="2688" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-2688h~iphone.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-2688h~iphone.png" width="2688" />
        <splash height="1792" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-1792h~iphone.png" width="828" />
        <splash height="828" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-1792h~iphone.png" width="1792" />
        <splash height="2436" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-2436h.png" width="1125" />
        <splash height="1125" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-2436h.png" width="2436" />
        <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
            <string>We use your location for full functionality of certain app features.</string>
        </edit-config>
        <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription">
            <string>We use your location for full functionality of certain app features.</string>
        </edit-config>
    </platform>
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.100.8:8100" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.100.6:8101" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.100.12:8101" />
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
        <string>We use your location for full functionality of certain app features.</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription">
        <string>We use your location for full functionality of certain app features.</string>
    </edit-config>
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.43.185:8100" sessionid="e88ac2f5" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8100" sessionid="9ac4c3b8" />
    <engine name="android" spec="7.1.4" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.7" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^1.3.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" spec="^0.1.9" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-native-spinner" spec="^1.1.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" spec="^0.8.15" />
    <plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin" spec="^2.8.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^4.0.2">
        <variable name="GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To locate you" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder" spec="^3.2.2">
        <variable name="LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION" value="Use geocoder service" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-deeplinks" spec="^1.0.20">
        <variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="myapp" />
        <variable name="DEEPLINK_SCHEME" value="https" />
        <variable name="DEEPLINK_HOST" value="aromixgroup.com" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_2_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_3_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_4_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_5_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
        <variable name="DEEPLINK_2_SCHEME" value=" " />
        <variable name="DEEPLINK_2_HOST" value=" " />
        <variable name="DEEPLINK_3_SCHEME" value=" " />
        <variable name="DEEPLINK_3_HOST" value=" " />
        <variable name="DEEPLINK_4_SCHEME" value=" " />
        <variable name="DEEPLINK_4_HOST" value=" " />
        <variable name="DEEPLINK_5_SCHEME" value=" " />
        <variable name="DEEPLINK_5_HOST" value=" " />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="5.0.0">
        
        <variable name="APP_NAME" value="aromixgroup" />
        <variable name="FACEBOOK_HYBRID_APP_EVENTS" value="false" />
        <variable name="FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION" value="5.0.2" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-admob-free" spec="^0.27.0">
        
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

Comment: what Cordova version are you using?? Update you cordova CLI `npm i -g cordova@latest` and remove platform add add it again.

Comment: i will try it i hope solve the issue.

Comment: not solve the issue can you give another hint?

Comment: ionic web view version that i use 5.0.0
cordova v10
cordova-ios v 5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this cordova-ios version:

```
ionic cordova platform add ios@5.0.0
```

I had the same problem and I could upload my app with this version

Comment: not solve the issue 
ionic web view version that i use 5.0.0
cordova v10
cordova-ios v 5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Well I had this issue aswell on a running productive app.
Apple doesn't want you to use any UIWebView references within your app.

**Solution number 1 (properly)** would be to update your whole Ionic project with all the plugins you got where there are still some UIWebView references. This could take a while and even be impossible as I encountered a lot of outdated plugins where nobody is updating it properly.

**The way I did it to still use Ionic 3**

In your build script (I would do one instead of always typing all the commands in your bash) add the cordova platform version 5.1.1. For me only this version worked fine to still be compatible with Ionic 3 plugins and Apple not sending me this message ever again.

Then do an ionic cordova prepare ios/android.

This should do the trick:

```
ionic cordova platform add ios@5.1.1
ionic cordova prepare ios
```

Then you can open it up again on xCode and try to submit your app again.

Hope it helps you out bud!

Comment: i tried with the commands at solution 2 many times but still give the same message

Comment: for solution one you mean remove all plugins and install it again