# Getting error while uploading the ionic ios app. Deprecated UIWebView used in the application

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview, ionic4, wkwebview

*ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability.*

Getting this issue while uploading the new application which is developed in the ionic.
I tried so many solutions which are available but none of the work.

Also tried https://cordova.apache.org/howto/2020/03/18/wkwebviewonly.html this one but still getting error.

Configuration :

> Ionic:
>
> Ionic CLI          : 5.4.16 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
> Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1
>
> Cordova:
>
> Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)    Cordova Platforms
> : android 6.4.0, ios 5.1.1    Cordova Plugins   :
> cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
> 4.1.0, (and 9 other plugins)

Application contains pdf and did some operation on pdf.
PDF is static which is upload in assets folder.

Also attached **package.json** file.

```
{
  "name": "MyPdfProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/app-preferences": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/mobile-accessibility": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.17.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.11.10",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "call-number": "1.0.1",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-app-preferences": "^0.99.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information.git",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "~5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.0.0",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "4.2.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": "~0.0.2",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.0.943",
    "phonegap-plugin-mobile-accessibility": "^1.0.5",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.1",
    "@ionic/lab": "1.0.16",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-preferences": {},
      "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-mobile-accessibility": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.pdf" version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyPdfProject</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1200" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
    <preference name="Hostname" value="AQHA 2021 Rulebook" />
    <preference name="Scheme" value="https" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-preferences" spec="^0.99.3" />
    <plugin name="mx.ferreyra.callnumber" spec="~0.0.2" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-mobile-accessibility" spec="~1.0.5-dev" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~6.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="~3.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~5.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^5.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^4.1.0" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="^4.5.5" />
</widget>
```

So, how can I solve this issue. Please help.

Comment: user `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` plugin

Comment: `Add below code in config.xml`

<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />

Comment: @RaviAshara I already added <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" /> in config.xml file. And also add this in iOS <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" /> </feature> <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" /> staging config.xml.

Comment: Check this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61790543/itms-90809-deprecated-api-usage-existing-app-that-use-uiwebview-are-no-longer

Comment: I already tried this but not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm uninstall @ionic-native/ionic-webview
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
```

And install

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@5.0.0
npm install @ionic-native/ionic-webview@5.29.0
```

Add config.xml

```
 <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
    <preference name="Hostname" value="yourappname" />
    <preference name="Scheme" value="https" />
```

Platform remove and add

```
 cordova platform rm android (or ios)
 cordova platform add android (or ios)
```

If you are using plugins from this list, you should update or uninstall them.
https://ionicframework.com/blog/understanding-itms-90809-uiwebview-api-deprecation/

Comment: Tried this but getting the same error from the app store.

Comment: Hi. Can you share package.json and config.xml?

Comment: Updated the question. Added package.json and cofig.xml

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using an old version of the cordova CLI and old version of cordova-ios.

Upgrade that to the latest version (where WKWebView is already integrated)

Then if you still have a problem with this, use this plugin:
cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr

This worked for me, and I had the same problem as you..

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I followed these steps to solve the issue.

***Step 1:*** I installed the **WKWebView** plugin: [ionic's](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview).

***Step 2:*** Add `<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />` to your config.xml file.

***Step 3:*** Update the **InAppBrowser** plugin.

***Step 4:*** Run `cordova prepare ios` to apply the changes.

5.1.0 has a conditional compile-time flag that disables UIWebView. This is an initial fix to prevent the Apple warning from being triggered.

6.0.0 will remove the entirety of UIWebView. This is a breaking change with more changes needed, so it’ll be released. As of January 2020, no ETA for release is known but version 5.1.0 will work just fine.

*Follow these steps and the issue will resolve and application will successfully upload on the app store.*