# XMLHttpRequest Faults after WKWebView Upgrade on Ionic v1 project/app

Tags: cordova, uiwebview, wkwebview, cordova-ios, ionic-v1

After trying to upload my working app to the store, I was encountered with an error message from app store connect saying that I'm not able to use the UIWebview anymore since it's been deprecated so I've been forced to upgrade to WKWebView.

I followed the answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61790543/itms-90809-deprecated-api-usage-existing-app-that-use-uiwebview-are-no-longer/62216793#comment116420251_62216793) question

When I now try and log into my app, I get these errors on the Safari console:

> Origin ionic://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.demo.mywebsite.com/mobile/pages/login due to access control checks

> Failed to load resources: Origin ionic://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

In my config.xml I have this

```
<access origin="http://localhost:8080/*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

I also set the headers on my server PHP files via this way:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080/*");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type,authorization");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
```

I have my website hosted on Windows Server 2016. Prior to the WKWebView upgrade, it was all working fine but now, i'm not able to use the app at all as it contains a lot of HTTP requests.

**UPDATE**

I've just made these changes:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

As well as this on my server file:

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

I no longer get the `ionic://localhost` error and the `Failed to load resources` error but I am getting this error:

> Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### config.xml

> **Access**
> « Define the set of external domains the app is allowed to communicate
> with. The default value shown above allows it to access any server. »
> See [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html#access).

This setting has nothing to do with the `origin` of your app when performing requests.

According to your `config.xml`, your app is only allowed to communicate with `http://localhost:8080/*`. You obviously want to use `*` here (or your server url if your app only makes requests to your server).

```xml
<access origin="*"></access>
```

#### WKWebView

> **iOS Preferences**
> « Since version 3, apps are served from `ionic://` scheme on iOS by default.
>
> The default origin for requests from the iOS WebView is
> `ionic://localhost`. If `Hostname` and `iosScheme` preferences are set, then
> origin will be `iosSchemeValue://HostnameValue`.
>
> Values like `http`, `https` or `file` are not valid and will use default value instead. »
> See [documentation](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview#ios-preferences).

On your server, you need to allow the origin `ionic://localhost`.
Assuming you want Android devices to able to communicate with your server as well, you need to allow both `ionic://localhost` and `http://localhost`, or `*` to allow all origins.

#### Server

You can allow both origins in your server like that for example.

```php
$allowedDomains = ['ionic://localhost', 'http://localhost'];

if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $allowedDomains)) {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've just applied your answers but I am getting `Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credential flag is true.` as well as the control checks error still.

Comment: Alright, that means you can't use `*`. You must allow both origins instead. I have updated my answer with an example for your server.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I've just noticed that my PHP sessions doesn't seem to be persisting. Is there a way for this to work? I've just investigated it and it is seems to be the case.

Comment: You're welcome. I have no idea about PHP sessions not persisting. As this is off-topic, I invite you to create another question regarding this specific subject. Please accept my answer if it solved your issue, thank you :)