# How to fix iOS ITMS-90809?

Tags: xcode, cordova, meteor

After upload app to appstore, i have from apple email:
ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

Recomendation from this not works: https://cordova.apache.org/howto/2020/03/18/wkwebviewonly.html

Meteor 2.2
xcode 12.5

Comment: If you don't get an answer here you may ask in the Meteor Forums, too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61790543/itms-90809-deprecated-api-usage-existing-app-that-use-uiwebview-are-no-longer please check out this first :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage -- Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57722616/itms-90809-deprecated-api-usage-apple-will-stop-accepting-submissions-of-app)

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure you don't have any more plugins that reference UIWebView, check for any old plugins for that. Make sure you use a recent version of cordova-ios too and cordova.

You could test this in your config.xml:

```xml
<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
```

You may as well try https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine-v2 because https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine is deprecated.

Edit: the official cordova blog recommended two years ago:

```xml
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />

    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>

    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</platform>
```

and to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

Comment: Not works(
but cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine-v2 older