# ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage** - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, phonegap

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qxf3D.png
```

I am getting same error while uploading application to AppStore. Following is the detail information which I used in application.This is the detail plugins which we have used in our ionic iOS app. We are trying to resolved it from last 1 month but still not getting luck. We have updated almost all plugins with latest version but still we are getting this issue.
I have did the followed the Ionic Form and added some code into config.xml but still getting same issue.

```
This is the detail plugins which we have used in our ionic iOS app. We are trying to resolved it from last 1 month but still not getting luck. We have updated almost all plugins with latest version but still we are getting this issue.
```

I have did the followed the Ionic Form and added some code into config.xml but still getting same issue.

If someone has any idea please help.

```
**1. config.xml**

 <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
        <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
            <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
        </feature>
        <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />



**2. package.json**

    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.0",
        "@angular/cli": "~10.0.5",
        "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.0",
        "@babel/helper-define-map": "^7.13.12",
        "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
        "cordova-ios": "^6.2.0",
        "cordova-open-native-settings": "^1.5.3",
        "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^3.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^3.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.3",
        "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.12",
        "cordova-plugin-ble-central": "^1.3.1",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "^6.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-insomnia": "^4.3.0",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-ms-adal": "^0.10.2",
        "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
        "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^6.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^3.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.5",
        "cordova-plugin-wifiwizard2": "^3.1.1",
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.0",
        "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^6.0.2",
        "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.1.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
        "jetifier": "^1.6.6",
        "karma": "~5.0.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
        "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
        "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.1.0",
        "protractor": "~7.0.0",
        "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0",
        "typescript": "~3.9.5"
      }

**3. Used plugins:**

    cordova-open-native-settings 1.5.5 "Native settings"
    cordova-plugin-advanced-http 3.2.2 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
    cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter 1.1.3 "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter"
    cordova-plugin-androidx 3.0.0 "cordova-plugin-androidx"
    cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.12 "AppVersion"
    cordova-plugin-ble-central 1.4.1 "BLE"
    cordova-plugin-camera 6.0.0 "Camera"
    cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
    cordova-plugin-device 2.1.0 "Device"
    cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
    cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.1.0 "Geolocation",
    cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 5.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
    cordova-plugin-insomnia 4.3.0 "Insomnia (prevent screen sleep)",
    cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard",
    cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
    cordova-plugin-ms-adal 0.10.1 "ADAL for Cordova"
    cordova-plugin-nativestorage 2.3.2 "NativeStorage"
    cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.2 "Network Information"
    cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 3.0.2 "Screen Orientation"
    cordova-plugin-splashscreen 6.0.2 "Splashscreen"
    cordova-plugin-statusbar 3.0.0 "StatusBar"
    cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.5 "Whitelist"
    cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix 0.1.0 "WKWebView XHR Fix"
    cordova-sqlite-storage 6.0.0 "Cordova SQLite storage plugin - cordova-sqlite-storage 
    plugin version"
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic 6.1.0 "Diagnostic"
    es6-promise-plugin 4.1.0 "Promise"
    phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 8.1.0 "BarcodeScanner"
    wifiwizard2 3.1.1 "WifiWizard2"

**ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage** - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - existing app that use UIWebView are no longer accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61790543/itms-90809-deprecated-api-usage-existing-app-that-use-uiwebview-are-no-longer)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I find a similar issue on this question 2 years ago. Hope it's useful.
[ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - existing app that use UIWebView are no longer accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61790543/itms-90809-deprecated-api-usage-existing-app-that-use-uiwebview-are-no-longer)